# Is the phrase "in the weekend" really wrong? Or might there be some exceptions?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I have learned that "***in the weekend***" is a kind of weird expression, and that we should use "on the weekend" or "at the weekend" instead.

I, however, noticed that the phrase can be seen sometimes even on prestigious newspapers and magazines as in the below examples, and I just would like to confirm with you whether they are all errors or not. I'm curious if there's any exceptions.

> The Guardian
>  "I don't know if I'll be here next season". His
> comments came before his opposite manager on Saturday, Chris Hughton,
> was sacked later ***[in the weekend](https://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2014/apr/07/premier-league-10-talking-points-from-weekend)***.

> Financial Times
>  Although senior executives might not have been
> rushing to the office ***[in the weekend](https://www.ft.com/content/4cb747ee-c113-11e0-b8c2-00144feabdc0)***, most banks’ analysts
> were.......

> The New York Times
>  In Asia, where trading ended before Monday’s
> de-escalation, markets suffered steep losses, reflecting the trade
> turbulence earlier ***[in the weekend](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/25/business/global-markets.html)***.

> Time Magazine
>  The fifth winter storm of the season is forecast
> to move from the Mississippi and Ohio Valleys on Friday before pushing
> to the northeast and into New England later ***[in the weekend](https://nation.time.com/2013/12/13/winter-storm-electra-to-hit-eastern-third-of-u-s/)***.

---

POST EDIT (I added some more examples)

> BBC
>  The election committee gave no date for a declaring the
> result, but the speculation is that it might be announced ***[in the
> weekend](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-18554596)***.

> Nature
>  the total distance of taxis has a low peak in the
> afternoon of the working days, but not ***[in the weekend](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201926)***; the
> total distance of buses has two peaks in the morning of workdays but
> only one peak in the weekend.

> Forbes
> ***[In the weekend](https://www.forbes.com/sites/jrose/2019/04/16/high-school-band-director-quits-job-to-create-1-million-business-in-4-years/#4a0dd2557a11)*** of their first launch, Hoyt and Yanda made $120,000 in course sales.

> Sydney Morning Herald
>  And so it was ***[in the weekend](https://www.smh.com.au/world/in-the-us-now-is-never-the-time-to-talk-about-climate-change-20170913-gygdrf.html)***,
> when a reporter was rude enough to ask US Environmental Protection
> Agency chief Scott Pruitt​ about the impact of climate change on
> monster hurricanes that have been smashing southern states, he
> responded:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Ngram Viewer shows 'early/earlier' and 'late/later' in the weekend, and also 'take part/participate'/'included'/'involved' in the weekend. Three of your examples include 'earlier' or 'later', and I would call the other (the Financial Times), plain wrong.

The usual explanation is that 'at the weekend' is British English and 'on the weekend' is American, but actual usage is more mixed. 'In the weekend' by itself *is* weird. Don't use it just because one major newspaper uses it.

Comment: Or "over the weekend."

Comment: @Sydney: Thanks. So, do you usually use "**in** the weekend" when it follows such words as *early/earlier and late/later*? Not "earlier/later **on** the weekend"? (I understand that words like *take part/participate/included/involved* take "in" idiomatically, so "take part in the weekend" makes sense to me too.)  Although I quoted just four examples in my initial posting, a lot more examples actually can be seen (note: I have added some more examples), and that's why I thought of a possibility of some exceptions.

Comment: I don't know what combinations I use. To confuse the issue: Google Ngrams shows that 'early/late *on* the weekend' and 'earlier/later *in* the weekend' are more common (but the other choices are used and correct).

Comment: @TypeIA added 'over the weekend'. That is most common in phrases like 'talk/think about it over the weekend' and 'be/stay/go/come/take home over the weekend'.